# Ant builds the Test Project Successfully, but eclipse throws error

Tags: android, eclipse, ant, cmd

I have created one Android Project with Ant build. And also created Test Project for it, which also has the ANT build.
Both the projects can build smoothly through cmd as well as in eclipse. But the problem is that, though the eclipse console is showing the message build successful (In case of test project), eclipse file explorer shows tonnes of errors in my files. So I am not able to run the project thru eclipse.

Is not a weird behaviour of Eclipse ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are building with `ant` you should disable Eclipse's automated build (*Project -> Build Automatically*).
Then, every time you want to build, right click on build.xml and *Run As -> Ant Build.* Be sure you have ant build target defined accordingly to your project's needs.

Answer (score 0):

I have had eclipse report errors incorrectly. Try modifying one of your source files in Eclipse (add a space somewhere). This will cause eclipse to re-build, and sometimes gets rid of errors that aren't supposed to be there.

Comment: No I tried that way. I also removed imported files and asked eclipse to import it but same problem persists